# MATLAB: How To Efficiently Remove NaN Elements from Matrix

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to remove the NaN numbers from a matrix in MATLAB efficiently (i.e. without using a for loop)

I will provide a quick example to illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

Say I have a matrix M:

```
          3.00          1.00
          1.00          3.00
           NaN           NaN
          3.00          3.00
          1.00          1.00
           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN
           NaN           NaN
```

I would like to find a way to change this to

```
          3.00          1.00
          1.00          3.00
          3.00          3.00
          1.00          1.00
```

I am currently trying to do this via M(isfinite(M)) but that ends up returning a vector instead of the matrix. Is there a trick to have it return a matrix instead?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have either no NaNs or all NaNs on each row, you can do the removal using:

```
M(isfinite(M(:, 1)), :)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Do you know if this is faster than the reshape command suggested by Steve?

Comment: Use this scheme. This is surely more efficient than using the reshape AFTER removing all of the nans.

Comment: @jeremiah-willcock @woodchips ... how can we do this for columns `M(all(isnan(M), 1), :) = [];` for some reason didn't work. I transposed and used this but there should be a better method. Thanks

Comment: That would remove `inf` values as well. Better use `M(~isnan(M(:, 1)), :)`

Answer (score 20):

The best way is

```
M(any(isnan(M),2),:)=[]
```

which will remove any row that contains at least one NaN.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would like to recommend a slightly different (and more general) approach.

So, in case that you want to ignore (i.e. delete) all the rows where at least one column includes `NaN`, then just:

```
M= M(0== sum(isnan(M), 2), :)
```

Comment: I'd suggest `M = M(~any(isnan(M), 2), :)`

Answer (score 1):

try my **`snip function`**. I wanted to address typical questions like this in one simple function:

```
B = snip(A,nan)
```

you can find the [function file at](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41941-snip-m-snip-elements-out-of-vectorsmatrices)

It also works with all other **'x', '0'** or whatever elements and takes care of more similar problems.

Comment: It seems to work but does not feel intuitive. Use the string `'1'` to remove the value 1. But use the value `nan` to remove the value `nan`. And what are you supposed to do if you want to remove the character `'1'`? --- I think the things it can do may be reasonable, but the way you have to ask for it is just a pain. It is also not clear what happens when higher dimensions are involved.

Answer (score 1):

The following function removes NAN from the data for specified dimensions:

```
function data_out = remove_nan (data_in, remove_dim)
%remove row or col from the data_in if there is a NaN element

% e.g., data_in =[1 2 3 4 NaN; 1 2 3 4 5; 1 2 3 NaN NaN]
% from this data remove col 4 and 5 such that data_out=[ 1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2
% 3]

if nargin==1

    col_loc=any(isnan(data_in),1);
    data_in(:,col_loc)=[];
    data_out=data_in;

elseif nargin==2

    if remove_dim=='col'
        %find the cols with nan and remove the colums
        col_loc=any(isnan(data_in),1);
        data_in(:,col_loc)=[];
        data_out=data_in;
    elseif  remove_dim='row'
        %find the rows with nan and remove the rows
        row_loc=any(isnan(data_in),2);
        data_in(row_loc,:)=[];
        data_out=data_in;
    end
else
    error( 'incorrect no of arguments')

end
```

Comment: if you are writing a function for it, why `remove_dim` is a string? why supporting only 2D arrays? why not supposting N-D arrays and working with "along-dimension" argument much like [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) and many others?

Comment: It will probably work, but it seems like this answer has both high complexity and low flexibility. At least the dimension input should simply be a number, which would greatly simplify your code as well.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin It works and I use it for huge data sets in TB, specially in CSV files. I was looking for a function on 2D data set / databases for row or column oriented data and could not find one. SO thought of sharing. It can be extended for N-Dimension.