# Find Rows in MAtrix that have NAN values and delete them

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB: How To Efficiently Remove NaN Elements from Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202680/matlab-how-to-efficiently-remove-nan-elements-from-matrix)

I got code that does it below but its a little slow (the matrix is big) is there a better way to do it?

```
errorMat=isnan(rates);
errorRows=ind(errorMat);
for i=1:length(errorRows)
   rates(:,errorRows(i)) = [];
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rates(any(isnan(rates), 2), :) = [];
```

Alternatively:

```
rates = rates(~any(isnan(rates), 2), :);
```

I think the second approach is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[rows, cols] = find(isnan(rates)); 
rates(unique(rows),:) = []
```

disclaimer: untested as I'm not with Matlab in this machine and Octave is complaining about the `unique` function.

Comment: I did a test and it worked here.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation - sum with `NaN`s returns a `NaN`, so

```
rates(isnan(sum(rates,2)),:) = [];
```

Comment: seems a tic toc analysis is in order here :p