# Removing NaNs from vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to remove nans from two vectors, the vectors have to be the same length, so if I remove a nan in one vector, the corresponding value in the other vector must be removed even if it is not a nan. For example:

```
x = [1 nan 3 4 5]
y = [6 7 8 nan 10]
```

I would like to remove the nan in x, as well as the 7 in y. Also, I would like to remove the nan in y and the 4 in x, this way the vectors stay the same length. This question is similar to one asked here [MATLAB: How To Efficiently Remove NaN Elements from Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202680/matlab-how-to-efficiently-remove-nan-elements-from-matrix#)   , but I'm new to MATLAB and I am unsure of how to do the same with vectors instead of matrices. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use Choward's answer below instead of Brainkz's. It is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x = [1 nan 3 4 5]
y = [6 7 8 nan 10]
id1 = find(isnan(x));
id2 = find(isnan(y));
x([id1,id2]) = []
y([id1,id2]) = []
```

Output:

```
x =
     1     3     5
y =
     6     8    10
```

Explanation:

```
find(isnan(x));
```

Creates a vector with indices of NaNs in `x`. The same we do for `y`. Then, we concatenate two vectors using `[id1,id2]`. Finally, `x([id1,id2]) = []` removes elements from vectors where NaNs are present.

Answer (score 4):

This will ensure your vectors x and y remain the same size as each other but also that you only have the (x,y) pairs that are meaningful.

```
ind = ~isnan(x) & ~isnan(y) ;
xn = x(ind);
yn = y(ind);
```

Comment: `ind = ~isnan(x) & ~isnan(y)` is the more common syntax in MATLAB

Comment: @Dan I don't know if you're correct. The common AND is normally "&&". However, you need to use this "and()" function for vectors. It won't work using the normal "&&". I will have to see if this single "&" works for the vector case.

Comment: No, [`&&`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) is the short-circuiting operation you use on scalars for evaluating conditionals, [`&`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) is identical to `and` (explicitly in the docs) and is the elementwise and operator. Writing `and(x,y)` instead of `x & y` is very uncommon, in fact I have never seen anyone do it. It's like writing `plus(x,y)` instead of `x + y`

Comment: @Dan oh well awesome! You learn something new every day! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I think you should edit your answer, because other than that your solution is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient solution for memory management and speed is to remove values from your existing arrays using logical indexing, rather than creating new arrays.

```
xn = isnan(x); yn = isnan(y); % find the locations of the NaNs
x(xn | yn) = []; % delete elements from x that are NaN in x OR y
y(xn | yn) = []; % delete elements from y that are NaN in x OR y
```

But you won't notice the performance difference unless you have very large arrays.