# How to query list of variables in Matlab struct matching a certain pattern?

Tags: regex, matlab, struct, octave, matlab-struct

Suppose I have the following `struct` in Matlab (read from a JSON file):

```
>>fs.
fs.dichte              fs.hoehe               fs.ts2                 
fs.temperatur          fs.ts3                 fs.viskositaet
fs.ts1                 fs.ts4
```

Each one of the `fs.ts*` components contains another `struct`. In this particular case, the index of `ts` goes from 1 to 4, but in another case it could as well be 2 or 7. You get the idea, right? I want the program to be flexible enough to handle any possible input.
So my question comes down to: How to query the maximum index of `ts`?
In an ideal world, this would work:

```
who fs.ts*
```

But unfortunately, it just returns nothing. Any ideas?

(*Btw, I'm using Octave and don't have Matlab available for testing; however, there should really be a solution to this which works in both environments.*)

Comment: Not an answer to your exact question but sounds like instead of `tsN` fields, you should have a single `ts` field with a list. Tip: every time you see a number in a variable or field name, think whether you shouldn't be using a vector/array/list instead.

Comment: Great idea; I've been using JSON only for a short time, so I didn't think of that solution. So I replaced my four `tsN` by an array of objects called `ts`. It is correctly parsed by `loadjson`. But how can I access the substructures? `fs.ts(1)` works and outputs the structure, which contains more variables, e.g. `laenge` and `hoehe`. But `fs.ts(1).laenge` gives: `error: cell cannot be indexed with .`

Comment: You need to use curly brackets when indexing a element from a cell array. If you use parentheses, then you get a back a cell array slice. So use `fs.ts{N}` which returns element N of the cell array, instead of `fs.ts(N)` which returns a cell array with the element N.

Comment: Right, this way it works. Why didn't I think of that myself? :-s
What's confusing me though is the fact that, although `fieldnames(fs.ts{1})` renders the correct result, autocompletion doesn't work here, so if I type `fs.ts{1}.` at the interactive prompt and press TAB, the variables are not listed (the output gives `./        ../       .nargin.`). Is this not yet implemented in Octave GUI, or a general lack of the language? Does Matlab act the same way?

Comment: Octave relies on readline for autocompletion. What you suggest is a possible improvement to Octaves readline configuration. Please suggest that in the [Octave bug tracker](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fieldnames` to get all field names of the struct, then use `regexp` to extract the ones that start with `ts` and extract the number. Then you can compare the numbers to find the largest.

```
fields = fieldnames(fs);

number = str2double(regexp(fields, '(?<=^ts)\d+$', 'once', 'match'));
numbers = number(~isnan(number));

[~, ind] = max(number);
max_field = fields{ind};
max_value = fs.(max_field);
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helped me out.
I slightly modified your approach, since in the next step, I'm looping over `tsN`:
`numberOfParts = str2double(regexp(fields, '(?<=^ts)\d+$', 'once', 'match'))';`
`numberOfParts = numberOfParts(~isnan(numberOfParts(1, :)))` (from the comments of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5202703).
Then I can do `for i = numberOfParts` and so on...

Comment: @rotton I incorporated this into the answer. Consider marking this as the solution if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your exact question but sounds like instead of `tsN` fields, you should have a single `ts` field with a list.

*Tip: every time you see a number in a variable or field name, think whether you shouldn't be using a vector/array/list instead.*

This is true for all languages but more so for Octave since everything is arrays. Even if you have three field named `ts1`, `ts2`, and `ts3` with scalars values, what you really have is three fields whose values are an array of size 1x1.

In Octave you can have two things. Either the value of `ts` is a cell array, each element of the cell array a scalar struct; or is a struct array. Use a cell array of structs when each struct has different keys, use a struct array when all structs have the same keys.

### Struct array

```
octave> fs.ts = struct ("foo", {1, 2, 3, 4}, "bar", {"a", "b", "c", "d"});
octave> fs.ts # all keys/fields in the ts struct array
ans =

  1x4 struct array containing the fields:

    foo
    bar

octave> fs.ts.foo # all foo values in the ts struct array
ans =  1
ans =  2
ans =  3
ans =  4

octave> numel (fs.ts) # number of structs in the ts struct array
ans =  4

octave> fs.ts(1) # struct 1 in the ts struct array
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    foo =  1
    bar = a

octave> fs.ts(1).foo # foo value of the struct 1
ans =  1
```

### Cell array of scalar structs

However, I'm not sure if JSON supports anything like struct arrays, you will probably need to have a list of structs. In that case, you will end up with a cell array of struct scalars.

```
octave> fs.ts = {struct("foo", 1, "bar", "a"), struct("foo", 2, "bar", "b"), struct("foo", 3, "bar", "c"), struct("foo", 4, "bar", "d"),};
octave> fs.ts # note, you actually have multiple structs
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      foo =  1
      bar = a

  [1,2] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      foo =  2
      bar = b

  [1,3] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      foo =  3
      bar = c

  [1,4] =

    scalar structure containing the fields:

      foo =  4
      bar = d

}
octave-gui:28> fs.ts{1} # get struct 1
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    foo =  1
    bar = a

octave-gui:29> fs.ts{1}.foo # value foo from struct 1
ans =  1
```

Comment: Well, although @Suever 's solution solves my specific problem, your answer/comments made me rethink my data structure. So this leads me to several other questions. Should I open a new one then?
I have a sample JSON file I could share publicly. Since SX does not let me upload files, I'd need to use pastebin or something similar...

Comment: You should create a new question since it sounds like your new issues are very different from this. You shouldn't need to upload files or to use pastebin. You should create a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.